# Buffer Overflow protections in custom library

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

Does a custom library affected by a buffer overflow need to be compiled with protections even if it is linked against an executable which already has protections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile-time protections in an executable do not confer protection to code in linked libraries, or vice versa. If you have an executable linked against a library, both the library and the executable must be compiled with protections if you want to protect the entire thing. If only the executable or only the library has the protections, then vulnerabilities present in the code that is *not* protected may be exploitable.